# High CPU usage in Kurento media server

Tags: webrtc, cpu, kurento

I am running Kurento with kurento player tutorial and see that kurento-media-server process takes about 20-25% CPU per stream. Is it way to reduce CPU usage?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you get any solution ?